# handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101 in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have facing this error even though code runs and gives output, this error part is given especially when it is on .get() or is it?.I have tried solutions of other SSL error code but doesn't seem to work sometimes, gives 44 links as required but sometimes it gives only 10 or 20, it seems inconsistent and what is SSL error code 1, net_error -101 mean?

Also, tried increasing delay in time.sleep() but doesn't seem to help?

 In headless mode, it is giving:
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, did get any solution for this, also? for this tried CORS extension and it also didn't work.
Console output:

```
[2664:25084:0119/211237.647:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211238.068:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211238.842:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -113
[2664:25084:0119/211238.844:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -113
[2664:25084:0119/211253.591:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211253.879:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211253.959:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211253.963:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[2664:25084:0119/211254.251:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211255.211:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[2664:25084:0119/211255.788:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[2664:25084:0119/211319.752:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211319.973:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211320.001:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211320.228:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211320.285:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211320.507:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
I am here
[2664:25084:0119/211350.324:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211350.536:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211350.589:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211350.795:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
I am here
Going Down
Going Down
[2664:25084:0119/211420.337:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211420.562:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211420.594:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211420.823:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
Going Down
Going Down
Going Down
[2664:25084:0119/211450.376:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211450.607:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211450.647:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[2664:25084:0119/211450.861:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
44
```

CODE:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    import re
    from dateutil.parser import parse
    import scrapy
    #To avoid bot detection
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
    #options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
    #browser.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
    #browser.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
    #print(browser.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
    ##################################################
    #options=options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
    browser.set_window_size(1280, 800)
    
    
    #time.sleep(20)
    base_url='https://www.legacy.com/obituaries/bostonglobe/obituary-search.aspx?daterange=88888&startdate=20190101&enddate=20210119&townname=Abington&countryid=1&stateid=22&affiliateid=1232'
    print('Gttibg url')
    browser.get(base_url)
    time.sleep(50)
    print("I am here")
    last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("I am here")
    while True:
                
            # Scroll down to the bottom.
                browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    
            # Wait to load the page.
                time.sleep(10)
    
            # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height.
                new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
                time.sleep(5)#***************************
                print('Going Down')
                if new_height == last_height:
    
                    break
    
                
                last_height = new_height
    time.sleep(20)
    links=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a')
    print(len(links))
    for i in links:
        
        print(i.get_attribute('href'))
        print(i.text)
```

How to avoid this error?